# Horizontal scrolling jQuery fixed navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a web page that has a horizontal scrolling effect such as this one http://retrousse.co.uk/lookbook, i am currently using this example as a template http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/WebsiteScrolling/

However I cant work out how to keep the navigation and logo div centred on the page whilst you horizontally scroll. Does anyone know how i can achieve this?

Comment: I can tell from the links what your question is, but you should post the main structure of your code inside the question so it is easier for people to understand. The linked sites may not be there or the same tomorrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix the position to the viewport.

`<div id = "navigation" style="position:fixed">`

This will keep the div at what ever location you set it at using `top:'500px'; left:'200px;'` etc.